# javascript google places works in html but not inside asp content

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms, google-places

I am trying to use a javascript example using google places api to auto fill some address fields.  It works as planned in html but if I am wanting to use it inside  tags it does not work.  I am not seeing any js errors in firefox.  I am thinking that I am not calling the javascrip correctly.  Help is greatly appreciated. My code for the asp page, js file, and site.master are as follows:

test.aspx asp head

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.test" %>
```

test.aspx page

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" onload="javascript:initialize()">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/auto_complete.js"></script>

<div id="locationField">

</div>
  <div id="consent-form-container">

  <div class="box">
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Type Your Address:"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox id="autocomplete" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="javascript:geolocate()"></asp:TextBox>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Apt/Suite:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="apt_suite1" runat="server" type="text" CssClass="apt_suite"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
       </tr>                
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Street address</td>
      <td class="slimField"><asp:TextBox class="field" runat="server" id="street_number" type="text" disabled="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" type="text" disabled="true"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">City</td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><asp:TextBox class="field" runat="server" id="locality" type="text" disabled="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">State</td>
      <td class="slimField"><asp:TextBox class="field" runat="server" id="administrative_area_level_1" type="text" disabled="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField"><asp:TextBox class="field" runat="server" id="postal_code" type="text" disabled="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

auto_complete.js

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var component_form = {
    'street_number': 'short_name',
    'route': 'long_name',
    'locality': 'long_name',
    'administrative_area_level_1': 'short_name',
    'postal_code': 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('<%= autocomplete.ClientID %>'), { types: ['geocode'] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();
    });
}

function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in component_form) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = "";
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
        var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
        if (component_form[att]) {
            var val = place.address_components[j][component_form[att]];
            document.getElementById(att).value = val;
        }
    }
}

 function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }
}
```

and site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Project.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head id="head" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> title </title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">     
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>  
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body id="body" runat="server">
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Site Scripts--%>

    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">
                <a runat="server" href="~/"><img src="/Images/logo.png" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>  
        <div class="float-right">
            <section id="login">
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <p>
                            Welcome admin!, <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/admin" title="" style="color:white">
                                <!--<asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" ForeColor="White" />-->View Forms</a>
                            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Logout" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                        </p>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body_div">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
    </section>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Riviera Tanning Spa</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change js like this

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_autocomplete")
```

Comment: I tried but it still isn't working.  It's got to be something simple I'm missing here..right? :)

Comment: in firefox can you "inspect item" (dont know exact name of the command but it was something like that in chrome when u right click any item in browser) your "autocomplete" textbox and check what is the "id" of it? or just check the sourcecode or your page to find the id. it should be "MainContent_autocomplete" with masterpages, but maybe its something different..

Comment: Here is something I found,  The Autocomplete constructor takes two arguments:

    An HTML input element of type text. This is the input field that the Autocomplete service will monitor and attach its results to.   I found this info here....https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete    Maybe this can only be used with html tags of type text?? sorry I've been afk for over a week.

Comment: your autocomplete textbox in your aspx page renders as html input element of type text. you can check the source-code of your page in your browser to find out. also you can find the "id" of that input, and put that in your javascript, thats the problem usually.

Comment: You are absolutely correct....here is the tag, <input name="ctl00$MainContent$autocomplete" id="MainContent_autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" />  NOW I SEE what you were talking about with checking the id

Comment: Here is what I see will be a problem.  When I use a master page and use asp content the rendered id adds "MainContent_" to the id's.  The javascript example I am using requires the id of the text fields to equal that of a google places component type such as "postal_code" so when the html is rendered the id's have the wrong name for the js code.  There has got to be an easy answer to this...

Comment: The way my autocomplete.js is coded it is better not to use a master page with this page.  I could also alter the autocomplete.js file to make this work.

Comment: OK, because I'm such a newb to asp(more of a java guy) the answer to this is of course painfully obvious.  All that needed to be added was ClientIDMode="Static" to my <asp:TextBox/> tag.  Easy peasy